# Assign Backbone model to view after view has been instantiated?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Was wondering how I add a model view when the view has already been instantiated? I've created a switch statement to make the correct view but then once this is done I then want to bind the model? I've tried `set` and `view.model = model` with no success?

**JS**

```
var type = 'typeOne';

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var ViewTypeOne = Backbone.View.extend();
var ViewTypeTwo = Backbone.View.extend();

var model = new MyModel({
    'name': 'James Bond'
});

var newView;
switch (type) {
    case 'typeOne':
        newView = new ViewTypeOne();
    case 'typeTwo':
        newView = new ViewTypeTwo();
}

newView.model = model;

console.log('After', newView.model.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if/how you can bind the model to an instantiated view, but I do know how you can solve your problem in one of several ways:

1. Pass the model as a parameter when you instantiate the view in the `switch`:

   ```
   var model = {model: this.model};
   var newView;
   switch (type) {
     case 'typeOne':
       newView = new ViewTypeOne(model);
     case 'typeTwo':
       newView = new ViewTypeTwo(model);
   }
   ```
2. Pick the view type in the `switch`, and then instantiate with the model:

   ```
   var viewType;
   switch (type) {
     case 'typeOne':
       viewType = ViewTypeOne;
     case 'typeTwo':
       viewType = ViewTypeTwo;
   }
   var newView = new viewType({model: this.model});
   ```
3. Use a map to link names to types, and get rid of the `switch`:

   ```
   var views = {
     'typeOne': ViewTypeOne,
     'typeTwo': ViewTypeTwo
   }
   var newView = new views[type]({model: this.model});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `new ViewTypeOne({ model: this.model })`?

You may want to instantiate your view with the model passed, since in some cases the model is needed for initialization.

Comment: But would this mean I'd need to add the model: this.model into each case of my switch? Trying to cut down on that, making the instantiation then binding the model after?